# Deleting files gives an error (The process cannot access the file..)

Tags: c#, system.io.directory

I'm currently debugging my code because it gives me an error:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

And i think that the error occurs in this lines of code

```
foreach (var filename in filenames)
{
    var file = Path.Combine(filePath, filename);
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file));
}

// Send Mail
smtpServer.Send(mail);

DeleteFiles();
```

I want to delete the files in the folder when the mail is sent using this method

```
private void DeleteFiles()
{
    string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/attachments");
    Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(filePath), System.IO.File.Delete);
}
```

I read about closing/disposing? FileStream and etc. but how can i use that in my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think the error is in these lines of code? Have you set breakpoints and single stepped through your code to see where it throws the error?

Comment: I think you need to dispose of the data you're sending via mail. It's possible that the mail server has a lock on the file.

Comment: @StillLearnin because when i put DeleteFiles() before the foreach it's working but when it is placed after foreach it gives me the error.

Comment: How do you know that the problem isn't caused by smtpServer.Send(mail)? Your code shows DeleteFiles() to be after this call. try putting it before this call and see if it can delete the files.

Comment: Because the mail is sent successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mail.dispose();` You should dispose mail before deleting the file. This **should** remove the lock on the file.

```
foreach (var filename in filenames)
{
    var file = Path.Combine(filePath, filename);
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file));
}

// Send Mail
smtpServer.Send(mail);
mail.Dispose();
DeleteFiles();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w54a951(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Great, it helps for my issue also

Answer (score 1):

```
using(FileStream stream = new FileStream("thepath"))
{
      //do stuff with the file
      stream .Close();
}
```

Now the stream will be closed and disposed.

Comment: The `stream.Close()` at the end is redundant

Comment: @BroSlow suspected so but I didn't test so I added it to be sure

Comment: There is no need to using stream.close at the end of the using statement. The using statement takes care of it for you.

Comment: Thanks to your answer but it's not the code i used.

Comment: stream.Close is redundant in that using block